# How to store images in SQLite database in Julia?

Tags: julia, genie.jl

I am using Searchlight in Genie Julia framework. How to store a image in SQLite database?

Comment: Are you sure you really need to store images in DB? For large binary blobs, we usually store file paths in DB.

Comment: usually it's done using BLOB but I am not sure how to use it. You can join Genie discord to ask this from Adrian: https://discord.gg/9zyZbD6J7H

Comment: alternatively you can also use file paths(path to image in disk)

Answer (score 2):

While usually it is better to store the path to the image, a solution is straightforward - just use `BLOB` and parametrized queries.

Consider the following table (note the `BLOB` type:

```
SQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Images
                                   (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                   name TEXT,
                                   imdata BLOB)
                                 ")
```

Suppose you have some image:

```
im0 = Images.load(raw"c:\temp\small.png")
```

This image can be simply stored by using parametrized query:

```
DBInterface.execute(db, "INSERT INTO Images (name, imdata) VALUES (?, ?)", ["somename", im0])
```

It can be simply retrieved:

```
julia> dat = DBInterface.execute(db, "SELECT * FROM Images") |> DataFrame
1×3 DataFrame
 Row │ ID     name      imdata
     │ Int64  String    Matrix
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │     1  somename  RGB{N0f8}[RGB{N0f8}(1.0,0.498,0.…
```

And you can check that it has been correctly stored:

```
julia> dat.imdata[1] == im0
true
```